# Meaning of the default buffer size(8KB) of ' BufferedInputStream ' ? (JAVA)

Tags: java, file-io, bufferedinputstream

I was first curious about how the buffer size of 'BufferedInputStream' class is decided for each program. I found out in STACKOVERFLOW that the default buffer size is 8KB.

I wonder if there is profound meaning in the default buffer size of
'BufferInputStream' class, which is 8KB in size.

When I searched java docs for information about the 'BufferedInputStream' class, 
I found out there are two forms of constructors for the class.
One constructor form offers users the ability to change the buffer size.

BufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)

1. Could the buffer size of this class be critical in deciding performance of some programs? I'm curious if anyone uses the above form of the constructor to change the buffer size to fit/optimize his/her program.
2. Is there any profound meaning to the default buffer size of 8KB?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could the buffer size of this class be critical in deciding performance of some programs? I'm curious if anyone uses the above form of the constructor to change the buffer size to fit/optimize his/her program.

Probably not. Changing from a buffer size of 1 to 2 will about double your performance (by reducing system calls). Changing from 2 to 4 will double it again. Changing from 4 to 8, again. You get the idea. At some point this ceases being true, as the performance ceases being dominated by system calls and starts being dominated by transfer sizes. 8k is a good place to stop. Use more if you like but you won't notice much difference.

> Is there any profound meaning to the default buffer size of 8KB?

There isn't. It is 8k in size. By default. That's the meaning. You can change it via a constructor. Nothing more to it.

Comment: there is a _profound meaning_ in 8KB: 4KB is the default and recommended block size for NTFS, it is also default with linux. 8KB is twice of it. you'd better choose a multiple of your block size in order to be efficient.